# I have dropdown of gender and its data type is boolean in rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have dropdown of gender and its data type is boolean in rails4. 
I use below code to display dropdown of gender:

```
<%= f.select(:gender,  {"Female" => false, "Male" => true}, {:selected => (@user.gender?)}) %>
```

but when i click on update it raise below error:

> 'false' is not a valid gender

Comment: what is the `gender` property type in your model (the field type in your DB table)?

Comment: Seems like you have a validation in your model.If so, please post that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ashvin you can use radio button for gender as follow.

```
<%= f.label :gender %><br />
<%= f.label :gender, "Male", :value => "true"  %>
<%= f.radio_button :gender, true %>
<%= f.label :gender, "Female", :value => "false" %>
<%= f.radio_button :gender, false %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong,try with this

```
<%= f.select(:gender, [['Female',false], ['Male',true]], {:selected => (@user.gender?)}) %>
```

Comment: i already tried this but it not work
because when i update gender it take the value in string 
but i want to pass it in integer

Comment: @ashvin Do you have any validation in your model?

Comment: no there is not any validation.
and i bind this dropdown in devise edit profile.